# In a for..in loop, why doesn't Flow throw when accessing a possibly invalid property?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[Example here.](http://0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoA5AVwM4FMzYAuATgJYDGh6A3KquXAHZFgC2AngEK67EBcYAN6MAhq1wCiZRgHMANAVIAvCWEaZWAI14BfMAF4hqNWNXoASnEIALETnRzj2ZaoCMqHag7deAOmcqvjC4sjZgwMBgACrWxIjYYCIJuAAeAA64lLgAJqhQcMRgABTBhGAA1rjsYKSMbFw8xACURmBgDMxlAG4iMJj4ht6NANqV7AC6tG09fbhBITI21OGRAOrW1dlwuNiM6GU2pAk2cQgA)

Why doesn't flow raise an error as I loop over all properties of which one is number and hence does not have a length method?

```
const myBeer: {name: string, size: number} = {
 name: 'Rothaus',
 size: 1
}
myBeer.size.length // Throws as expected
for (let key in myBeer) {
  const value = myBeer[key];
  value.length; // Why doesn't this throw?
}
```

Comment: `myBeer.size` is defined as `number`. `value` has no type constraint.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought maybe he can infer that value is either string or number and thus calling length may go wrong...

Comment: Iterating over an object is a common dynamic pattern that is basically impossible to type check without making it incredibly inconvenient. For that reason, Flow takes a hands-off approach and gives you `any` when you access an unknown property of an object this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dynamically access an object's fields in a loop, the values can be anything. Even given that `myBeer`'s type is `{name: string, size: number}`, it could have other fields of any other type, so Flow can't even infer the the type as `string | number`.

For better or for worse, Flow infers the type of all these fields as `any`. I would have chosen `?any`, but there we are.

Even if you weren't using Flow, this is a good example of why you shouldn't iterate over mixed-type object maps. This type *feels* like a record, not a collection. So treat it like a record and access the fields you need directly.